# Camel Netty4 is causing infinite feedback loop

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I am trying to achieve a UDP handshake with camel netty4 component. Among receiving the hello message, the application will mark a flag in the hello message as *ACKed* and send it back to the originator (processRoute).

The timer route below is simulating the periodic hello message sent from UDP_REMOTE to our application (UDP_LOCAL). And the checkRoute checks whether the *ACKed* hello message is received by the originator.

With below code, it looks like that the component is causing infinite feedback loop. Core libs involved are camel-spring-boot (2.16.1) and spring-boot (1.3.2.RELEASE). I know that must be my mistake. It would be great if someone could show me the correct way of doing that. Thanks in advance.

```
    private static final String UDP_LOCAL = "netty4:udp://localhost:4466";
    private static final String UDP_REMOTE = "netty4:udp://localhost:8899";

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    private final class PrintProcessor implements Processor {
        private final String name;

        public PrintProcessor(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            byte[] body = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
            System.err.println(name + "\t[b]==>" + new String(body));
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteBuilder RouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("timer://poller?period=5s").process(exchange -> {
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("Hello" + counter.incrementAndGet());
                    System.err.println("Sending Hello...");
                }).to(UDP_LOCAL);
                from(UDP_LOCAL).id("processRoute").process(new PrintProcessor("processRoute")).to(UDP_REMOTE);
                from(UDP_REMOTE).id("checkRoute").process(new PrintProcessor("checkRoute"));
            }
        };
    }
```

The Log looks like this

```
Sending Hello...
processRoute    [b]==>Hello1
checkRoute  [b]==>Hello1
checkRoute  [b]==>Hello1
processRoute    [b]==>Hello1
checkRoute  [b]==>Hello1
checkRoute  [b]==>Hello1
processRoute    [b]==>Hello1
checkRoute  [b]==>Hello1
checkRoute  [b]==>Hello1
processRoute    [b]==>Hello1
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's related to the configuration of the request/response of the netty component.

1. "Local" receive a message, print it, and send it to "remote"
2. "remote" receive the message, print it... and send a response to the origin: which is "local"
3. "local" receive a message... cf 1

Check the `sync` property on the endpoint to disable the response on the `netty` component.

```
private static final String UDP_LOCAL = "netty4:udp://localhost:4466?sync=false";
private static final String UDP_REMOTE = "netty4:udp://localhost:8899?sync=false";
```

Comment: The suggested changes work, thanks a lot. I got one more question on the component. When I try to send a message to port 4466 via a java UDPClient, camel-netty4 throws **TooLongFrameException**. I have tried to use option **allowDefaultCodec=false&udpByteArrayCodec=true**, however seems that the message is not reaching the consumer. More than that, the **TooLongFrameException** has caused port 4466 to be closed, thus subsequent requests are throwing the **PortUnreachableException**. Any hints on that?

Comment: Just found that **allowDefaultCodec=false&udpByteArrayCodec=true** actually works, instead of setting the body in the  timer route as string, just set it as byte[] with **exchange.getIn().setBody(body.getBytes())**. It would be nice if  I can get some explaination of why **TooLongFrameException** happened. Cheers~